# Adding items to already defined Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

So I have a control which I defined with **ControlPanelItem**

**ShipmentGridView.xaml**

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Class="SmartShipping.BaseViews.ShipmentGridView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SmartShipping.MainRegionItems.CollectiveShipmentRegionItems"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:LanguageResources.Properties;assembly=LanguageResources"
>

<telerik:RadGridView.ControlPanelItems>
    <telerik:ControlPanelItem >
        ...
    </telerik:ControlPanelItem>

</telerik:RadGridView.ControlPanelItems>
```

I'm using it in other view like so:

**FileImportView.xaml**

```
 <baseViews:ShipmentGridView IsReadOnly="True"   x:Name="FileImportGrid">
```

Now I'd like to add a new ControlPanelItem but I'd like to still have the old one there. Is there any way to merge those two collectons ? So I can have it like this:

```
<baseViews:ShipmentGridView IsReadOnly="True"   x:Name="FileImportGrid"> 
   <baseViews:ShipmentGridView.ControlPanelItems>
    <OldCollection></OldCollection>
    <telerik:ControlPanelItem>
    ...
    </telerik:ControlPanelItem>
   </baseViews:ShipmentGridView.ControlPanelItems>
</baseViews:ShipmentGridView>
```

Or some other way ?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what are you looking for, but maybe a [CompositeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.90).aspx) is what may help you.

Comment: I'm looking for a way of not overriding the ShipmentGridView's controlPanelItems collection with new one but adding items to the old one